# In Swift, how to remove a UIView from memory completely?

Tags: swift, uiview, swift2

Please considering following code:

```
class myManager {
    var aView: UIView!

    func createView() {
        aView = UIView()
    }

    func removeView() {
        aView = nil // anything else?
    }
}
```

If I create a `UIView` like this and later I want to remove it, is this the correct way? Anything I should be aware of?

Comment: `aView.removeFromSuperview()`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In order to have `aView` to be deinitialised and removed from memory you need to make it unreferenced by anything that keeps a strong reference to it.  That means it should not be referenced by any part of your code, *and* by the UIKit view stack.

In your case it might look like this:

```
aView?.removeFromSuperview() // This will remove the view from view-stack
                             // (and remove a strong reference it keeps)

aView = nil                  // This will remove the reference you keep
```

On a side note, if you are removing the view, then you probably should not use `var aView: UIView!` but instead `var aView: UIView?`.

Answer (score -2):

```
class A {
    deinit {
        print("A deinit") // (2)
    }
}

class B {
    var a: A! = A()
    func killA() {
        a = nil
    }
}

let b = B()
if b.a == nil {
    print("b.a is nil")
} else {
    print(b.a)  // (1)
}
b.killA()
if b.a == nil {
    print("b.a is nil") // (3)
} else {
    print(b.a)
}
/*
A
A deinit
b.a is nil
*/

// warning !!!!!
print(b.a) // now produce fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
// you always need to check if the value of b.a is nil before use it
```