# How to remove MKMapView in memory?

Tags: ios, swift, memory, automatic-ref-counting

run a mapview in xcode waste too much memory, so that i want to remove the mapview when current ViewController dismiss:

```
deinit{
    mapView = nil
}
```

but in the debug navigator, memory didnt release in fact.
so , how  to release the memory when i remove the mapview?
thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Swift, how to remove a UIView from memory completely?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34555765/in-swift-how-to-remove-a-uiview-from-memory-completely)

Comment: Try to remove MapView holding view from its super view. Or check for any pointing references present currently or not.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, one way to release the allocated memory for your `mapView` outlet is to call the .removeFromSuperview() method, put this in your *viewDidDisappear* declaration

```
override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    mapView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

The superview (in this case my ViewController) was able to free the memory accordingly

Comment: i try this method , but the memory in debug navigator was still high

Comment: @Chaz if this didn't work properly then, as _alex_p_ pointed, you're using a _strong_ reference with your mapView and other objects in your program may be using it

Comment: I'm fetching same memory issue anyone have solution?

Answer (score 0):

Swift uses Automatic Reference Counting mechanism for memory management and this means that the object will be removed and unloaded from memory at the time when the reference count, which refer to the object becomes zero. If the object is not unloaded, it is likely that the program has other objects that use it. Try to go through the code and check that you don't set reference to it object inside  another objects